# 1 Laravel app, 2 domain names & different route groups

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have 2 projects that are related for several things:

- users table
- design
- assets
- features

Each project has it's own URL, project1.com and project2.com for the production environment and also project1.local (or local.project1.com, I don't care) and project2.local (or local.project2.com).

I know how to redirect those urls to my laravel folder, what I don't know is a **clean and secure** way to tell laravel:

- project1.com -> use route group 1
- project2.com -> use route group 2
- project1.local -> use route group 1
- project2.local -> use route group 2

Also, I'd like to manage my views like that:

- views/project1/
- views/project2/
- views/shared/ (some views would be common to the 2 projects)

It's fine if I have to call a route like that `project1.myfile` but maybe I can have a var containing 'project1' to use it in the route group.

For now I've tried something like that

```
Route::group([
    "domain" => "project2.{extension}"
], function($extension)
{

    Route::any("/about", array(
        'as' => 'About Test',
        'uses' => 'HomeController@showWelcome')
    );

});

// Same route group for project1
```

and in HomeController@showWelcome I have:

```
echo URL::route('About Test');
```

This line display something like: `http://project2.%7Bextension%7D/about`, I've tried to pass $extension to a function in the route but the same thing happens.

**How can I get the urls/route-groups working correctly and securely ?**

All help/comment is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What is your Laravel version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a route group for each subdomain and then use a 'before' filter on each group.

```
Route::filter('domain1', function($request)
{
    $uri = Request::path(); //this might be in $request
    $matches = preg_match('^https?:\/\/([a-zA-Z)]+)\./', $uri);
    $subdomain = $matches[1];
    Session::put('domain', $subdomain); //you can use Session::get('domain'); to retrieve this 
    //for your other conditional logic (like your views folders etc.)
    if(!($subdomain == 'domain1')){
        return false;
    }
    //check your matches to see if your subdomain matches, if it doesn't: return false
});
```

Then in your routes:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'domain1'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', function()
    {
        //
    });

    Route::get('something/else', 'someMethod@SomeController');
});
```

rinse and repeat for subdomain 2... etc.